# Qt - Merge 2 or more .mp3 files to a single file

Tags: c++, qt, audio, metadata

say I have two or more parts of 1 .mp3 file like :

- **x1**.mp3
- **x2**.mp3
- **x3**.mp3

The question is, how can I merge these files i.e, x1.mp3 & x2.mp3 & and x3.mp3 to a single
**x.mp3** using **Qt**/**C++**. While merging the files together, I want to take care of the ***metadata*** going from x1.mp3, x2.mp3, and x3.mp3 to **x.mp3** so that the media player does not confuse while reading the final file like I may need any one of the 3 available thumbnails and increment the total duration of audio in the final file **x.mp3** and other important stuff...

I have tried this but it causes the metadata issues:

```
QList<QFile> files;
QFile file1("x1.mp3"), file2("x2.mp3"), file3("x3.mp3");
files << file1;
files << file2;
files << file3; 
QFile outputFile("x.mp3");
for(auto &file: files) {
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    outputFile.write(file.readAll());
}

outputFile.flush();
outputFile.close();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have naively tried merging the files(QFile) together without thinking about the metadata

Comment: Abdul can you show the code in your question? Click the edit button to put it in :)

Answer (score 2):

How about trying ffmpeg to merge those mp3 files because mp3 has its own format and merging them directly will just create a corrupted mp3.

AFAIK ffmpeg also can manage the metadata stuff

Steps to do it:

1. place a ffmpeg executable in the relative directory of your program
2. generate a ffmpeg command in your program
3. maybe run the command in a thread or execute it using pthread

Comment: yes, I could use FFmpeg or VLC API but I am looking for the way it is done using qt or c++